# How to align Center the Component inside a Tab of a TabLayoutPanel in UiBinder (GWT)?

Tags: gwt

in ui.xml

```
<g:TabLayoutPanel barUnit='EM' barHeight='3'>
  <g:tab>
    <g:header size='7'><b>Income</b></g:header>
    <g:Label>Income</g:Label>
  </g:tab>
  <g:tab width="100%">
    <g:header size='7'><b>Cost</b></g:header>
    <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="costHTMLPanel" addStyleNames="{style.alignCenter}" />
  </g:tab>

</g:TabLayoutPanel>
```

myResource.css file

```
.alignCenter{
    align:center;
}
```

I put width="100%" into tab `<g:tab width="100%">` but it didn't work.

I also tried `<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="costHTMLPanel" addStyleNames="{style.alignCenter}" width="100%" />` but it also didn't work.

Also tried the following but didn't work either

```
  <g:tab >
    <g:header size='7'><b>Cost</b></g:header>
    <g:HTMLPanel width="100%" addStyleNames="{style.alignCenter}">
        <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="costHTMLPanel"  />
    </g:HTMLPanel>

  </g:tab>

 OR
.........
     <g:HTMLPanel width="100%" >
            <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="costHTMLPanel"  addStyleNames="{style.alignCenter}"/>
     </g:HTMLPanel>
..........

OR
<g:tab width="100%" addStyleNames="{style.alignCenter}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
text-align: center;
```

in your CSS file.

Comment: There is no such CSS rule as "align". There is a rule "text-align".